# dispatchKeyShortcutEvent not being called in a Chrome OS environment

Tags: java, google-chrome-os

I want to implement code to react to common shortcuts like Ctrl + S (save), Ctrl + Z (undo) in a Chrome OS environment.

I have added the following code in the activity:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyShortcutEvent(KeyEvent event) {
  if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_O) {
      openFile(); // Ctrl+O, Shift+O, Alt+O
      return true;
  } else if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_Z) {
      if (event.isCtrlPressed()) {
              undoLastAction();
              return true;
      }
  }
  return super.dispatchKeyShortcutEvent(event);
}
```

And I have added the `Window.Callback` to the activity:

```
public class ScMain extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener,      
        FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener, Window.Callback {
```

Android Studio displays the following message:

*ComponentActivity.dispatchKeyShortcutEvent can only be called from within the same library group prefix (referenced groupId=androidx.core with prefix androidx from groupId=[my app])*

Although the code compiles without error, the `dispatchKeyShortcutEvent` method is never called.

I can not find which dependency I should add in my gradle file. Or do I need additional code?

Comment: Is it possible to do that with an android app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by using `onKeyShortcut` instead

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyShortcut (int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.isCtrlPressed()) {
        switch (event.getKeyCode()) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_Z:
                UndoBtnFired(undoBtn);
                break;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_S:
                saveToFile(null);
                break;
            case KEYCODE_L:
                clearDrawnLinks(mContext);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```